# Howto clear or drop database with Hibernate & MySQL within a Java app

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, mariadb

Is there a **mysql query** (using MariaDB 10.x.x) or a **Hibernate HQL** in which all tables in a single database are deleted? Right now I am trying to use the code below, but it doesn't do anything to the database. Since I am using Hibernate 5.x.x, the `createSQLQuery` is depreciated; therefore I am using `createNativeQuery` **instead**.

```
tx = s.beginTransaction();
            Session s = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = s.beginTransaction();
            s.createNativeQuery("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
            s.createNativeQuery("DROP DATABASE restaurantapp");
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
```

Comment: You are connected to the database and then dropping the database. Doesn't sounds good approach.

Comment: so you are saying I should disconnect to the database and then drop it? If so, could you kindly give me the steps how to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

The SQL Command is fine but I didn't know that I need to add `.executeUpdate();` after each native query.

Solution code:

```
Session s = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = s.beginTransaction();
            s.createNativeQuery("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0").executeUpdate();
            s.createNativeQuery("DROP DATABASE restaurantapp").executeUpdate();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
```